# Utilizando Case no Order By com union

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, firebird

Estou com dificuldades em utilizar o Order by com Case no Union, Dessa forma funciona:

```
select tb_a.nr_rua, tb_a.cod_altura, tb_a.cod_posicao, tb_a.cod_lado where ......
union all
select tb_b.nr_rua, tb_b.cod_altura, tb_b.cod_posicao, tb_b.cod_lado where ......
order by
2,3,1
```

Agora se eu fizer assim, utilizando o case:

```
order by 2,
 (case when 4 = 'M' then 3 END) DESC,
 (case when 4 <> 'M' then 3 END),
1
```

Ou:

```
order by 2,
 (case when cod_lado = 'M' then cod_posicao END) DESC,
 (case when cod_lado <> 'M' then cod_posicao END),
1
```

Ou:

```
order by 2,
 (case when cod_lado = 'M' then 3 END) DESC,
 (case when cod_lado <> 'M' then 3 END),
1
```

Também não funciona. seguinte Erro:

```
Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Invalid command.
invalid ORDER BY clause.
```

Estou utilizando o Firebird.

Comment: Case se utiliza dentro do select, favor verificar na documentacao do firebird https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-case.html

Comment: Certo @Everson no meu caso, o que eu teria que usar para resolver meu problema?

Comment: select tb_a.nr_rua, tb_a.cod_altura, tb_a.cod_posicao, 
   case 
   when cod_lado = 'M' then 3
   when cod_lado <> 'M' then 4 
  end as cod_lado
where .....
union all
select tb_b.nr_rua, tb_b.cod_altura, tb_b.cod_posicao,
  case 
   when cod_lado = 'M' then 3
   when cod_lado <> 'M' then 4 
  end as cod_lado where ......
order by cod_lado

Answer (score 1):

Seu `order by` deve fornecer uma expressão que possa ser avaliada para cada registro. Quando você usa:

```
(case when cod_lado = 'M' then cod_posicao END) DESC,
```

Falta o resultado da expressão para os registros `cod_lado <> 'M'`.

Talvez você possa utilizar algo assim:

```
if(cod_lado = 'M', 0, 1)
```